# How to implement an XSLT file within HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt-2.0, xls

I'm trying to display a whole XML database through an HTML file, but in order to display all the elements, I need XSLT. Since I used Javascript for manipulation with the way the database is displayed, I assume I'll have to implement XSLT file within the HTML code, but I can't find a solution on how I'd go about doing so.

Comment: w3schools has an xslt demo that can get you off the ground, surprising it didn't come up in your question's background research...  http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp

Comment: Better start with the mozilla developer network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSLT or the microsoft developer network: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256069.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible to invoke an XSLT transformation from within Javascript. You can even use an XSLT 2.0 transformation with the help of Saxon-CE, which probably offers better cross-browser compatibility than the XSLT 1.0 processors shipped by the browser vendors.